# Is it possible to enable Apache Cassandra DB on Freeradius v3.2.x or v4.x is a must?

Tags: freeradius

Due to performance requirements, we are trying to implement Cassandra DB with FreeRadius and enable sql accounting. For this, we installed the stable version of FreeRadius 3.2.x following the recommendation of NetworkRadius.

We are unable to find the Cassandra sql module and driver by default with the official FreeRadius installation.

First, is it possible to use Cassandra with FR 3.2.x? If yes, can you brief of how to do so?

If not possible, then I guess, we need to move to FR v4.0 with the caveat of still under heavy development

Appreciate your help and advise

Thanks